# Remove X-Frame-Options iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, x-frame-options

I need to display a controller in a classic asp page as an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:55329/member/fund/?guid=<%=guid%>" width="100%" height="100%" border="0"></iframe>
```

I can display the Index page with no issues however when trying to create or edit the products, the page throw the following error:

> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN

To resolve the issue, I tried removing the X-Frame-Options and re-adding in the Base controller level:

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
 {
     Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
     Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
     base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Instead it adds two X-Frame-Option this not resolving the issue.

I have seen and tested this fix which resolves the issue. However, I do not want to make change in the global setting.
[This fix was referred in previous questions](https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/mvc5-prevents-your-website-being-loaded-in-an-iframe)

Any idea to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have override it on Result Executed:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Hope this helps